# не могу понять как вклинить кусок sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть код sql :

```
select jiraaction.author,actionbody, jiraaction.created as time_created_comment, jiraissue.pkey, jiraissue.created as time_created_issue
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%-26578%'
```

И теперь из полученного результата в столбиках :

- time_created_comment
- time_created_issue

нужно найти разницу с помощью функции AGE :

```
age (time_created_comment, time_created_issue)as time_response
```

в селект почему-то вставать не хочет .
Подскажите как использовать данную функцию правильно ?

Comment: А не надо использовать алиасы в выражении. Вместо них используйте исходные поля.

Comment: @Akina  спасибо ! помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно нужно было отталкиваться от исходных полей, а не использовать алиасы.

Работает! Спасибо!

Как итоговый запрос в PostgeSQL, c функцией AGE у меня получилось вот так :

```
select jiraaction.author,actionbody,  jiraissue.pkey, age (jiraaction.created, jiraissue.created)as time_response
from jiraaction 
inner join jiraissue on jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
where jiraissue.pkey like '%-26578%'
```

Comment: Если источник данных составляет более 1 таблицы - добавляйте алиас таблицы к КАЖДОМУ имени исходного поля. На производительность это не влияет, а от проблем в будущем может и уберечь..

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT author, actionbody, created as time_created_comment, jiraissue.pkey, jiraissue.created as time_created_issue, age(TIMESTAMP created, TIMESTAMP jiraissue.created) as time_response
FROM jiraaction 
INNER JOIN jiraissue ON jiraaction.issueid = jiraissue.id 
WHERE jiraissue.pkey LIKE '%-26578%'
```

Попробуйте так, ещё убрал алиасы, о которых писали выше.

Comment: *Вы же берете данные из jiraaction и не обязательно прописывать обращение к нему jiraaction.author, а вот для jiraissue нужно, т.к. вы присоединяете этот запрос.* ????? Кто Вам напел такую ересь?